# How to play every matches of a fixture in PES 2012?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2012

In PES 2012 for PS2, I have played every single game of all fixtures of LaLiga which is nearly 380 matches.

However in the PES 2012 PC version, I can only select a team and play only with that team. It needs multiple gamers to play with multiple teams.
Is there any way I can play the entire league alone in the PC version?